# From Microsoft Project to JIRA

Tags: ms-project, jira

I know that this is a topic that has been talked about a lot but I need to export a project from MS Project to JIRA. I know that there are a few JIRA addons to make this job but they are paid and my company does not have money to pay a license for this addon. So, does anyone know if there is any script or any way to make this work?

Comment: How much $$ does the license cost? They can afford to pay for a JIRA license and afford to pay you, and can afford the budget for the projects you're working on but they can't afford the addons to transition from one tool to another? Sounds fishy to me.

Answer (score 2):

you can use TaskAdapter: http://www.taskadapter.com

it supports Atlassian JIRA and Microsoft Project integration, among other systems. it is not free, but... it's a matter of how much of your own effort you want to spend on building a tool like that vs. buying a 3rd-party tool with support and all :)

Comment: Update - Task Adapter is now free and open-source (https://taskadapter.com/buy/)!
Not sure when that happened, but it's on the site.